# Amount of days before datetimeindex (using .loc and .iloc at the same time)

Tags: python, string, pandas, indexing, integer

So the problem at hand is simple but quite tricky. I have 3 variables `startdate, enddate` and an integer `i=250`. The index of the df is a DateTimeIndex. The problem exists because I need to use both .loc and .iloc at the same time.

- I have a dataframe starting before the start date and ending after the end date.
- I wish to have a pandas dataframe starting 250 days before my start date until my end date

I have found some ways to do it. But it does not strike me as 'the perfect way' to solve it. Maybe somebody has had the same issue, and solved it in a nice way or maybe somebody can confirm this is actually "fast".

My current solution:

```
index_startdate = list(df.index.date.astype(str)).index(startdate)
df2 = (df.loc[:enddate]).iloc[(index_startdate-250):]
```

I also thought about this:

```
df2 = pd.concat([(df.loc[:startdate]).iloc[-250:],df.loc[startdate:enddate]])
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use only [`DataFrame,loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) solution with subtract start datetime or [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) solution with [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for positions by labels:

**Sample**:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10)}, index=rng)  
print (df)

            a
2017-04-03  0
2017-04-04  1
2017-04-05  2
2017-04-06  3
2017-04-07  4
2017-04-08  5
2017-04-09  6
2017-04-10  7
2017-04-11  8
2017-04-12  9

startdate = '2017-04-07'
enddate = '2017-04-11'

#in real data change 2 to 250
s = pd.Timestamp(startdate) - pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=2)
df2 = df.loc[s:enddate]
print (df2)
            a
2017-04-05  2
2017-04-06  3
2017-04-07  4
2017-04-08  5
2017-04-09  6
2017-04-10  7
2017-04-11  8
```

---

```
#in real data change 2 to 250
s = df.index.get_loc(startdate) - 2
#slicing with iloc is exclusive of its endpoint, so added 1
e = df.index.get_loc(enddate) + 1

df2 = df.iloc[s:e]
print (df2)
            a
2017-04-05  2
2017-04-06  3
2017-04-07  4
2017-04-08  5
2017-04-09  6
2017-04-10  7
2017-04-11  8
```

Comment: The date offset won't work because it's a "trading dataset" so some days are banking holidays and you have the weekends of course. But I also thought this but it's more tedious to include "trading calendars". Right now I am using: `df2 = pd.concat([(df.loc[:startdate]).iloc[-250:], df.loc[startdate:enddate]])`